# Imagem maior que o Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

Preciso que a imagem de um gráfico, fique apenas dentro do Frame verde, dando para ver a imagem por completo. Alguém pode me ajudar a completar esse objetivo ?
Abaixo está a função atrelada ao botão SeletionSort, que quando clico nele aparece a imagem do gráfico.

```
def criaLabel(self, event):
        image = Image.open("barra.jpg")
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.label = Label(self.Frame3, text = "adicionando", image = photo)
        self.label.image = photo
        self.label.place(x = 0, y = 0)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

pegue a saida da chamada Image.open, e crie outra imagem reescalonada

```
image = Image.open("barra.jpg")
image2 = image.resize((100, 100))
```

Comment: Valeu Elton, me ajudou muito!!